# How to mix up rows in CSS Grid to remove empty space in between?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, css-grid

This is a css grid with multiple breakpoints and order change. I'm trying to fill the empty space (red arrow space) in the screenshot. I usually use flex, tried grid for the first time and I'm lost. Using tailwindcss in react.

Things to know - Office Notes, Experience will be loaded dynamically so their height can change.

[image: screenshot]

```
 <div className='grid grid-cols-1 lg:grid-cols-3 2xl:grid-cols-4 3xl:grid-cols-5 gap-x-6 gap-y-6 grid-flow-dense'>
   
            <div className='order-1'>

                <Account />

            </div>

            <div className='grid gap-y-6 lg:grid-cols-1 lg:col-span-2 lg:row-span-3 lg:content-start order-2'>

                    <OfficeNotes />

                    <Experience />

                    <UserLocation />

            </div>

            <div className='order-3 2xl:order-4'>

                <GigCount />

            </div>

            <div className='order-4 3xl:order-5'>

                <Pay />

            </div>


            <div className='order-5 2xl:order-3 '>

                <RatingPanel />

            </div>

            <div className="order-6 3xl:order-4">

                <Social />

            </div>

            <div className="order-7">

                <Emergency />

            </div>

        </div>
```

TIA

Comment: Please provide a Fiddle to help us to help you

Answer (score 0):

Use `grid-auto-flow: row dense;` so that you tell the browser to pack the cells as tightly as possible. In Tailwind there is this utility class that you can use: [`grid-flow-row-dense`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-auto-flow)

Comment: No, it didn't work. I'm already using grid-flow-dense in my main container. Are you suggesting that I should provide this in the children?